# What additional context can I add to make my question eligible for the site?

Tags: discussion

**EDIT:** the question got reopened thanks to the suggestions.

---

I got [my question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4507587/533020) closed with the following reason:

> Please provide additional context, which ideally explains why the question is relevant to you and our community. Some forms of context include: background and motivation, relevant definitions, source, possible strategies, your current progress, why the question is interesting or important, etc.

The question is relevant since it resembles an actual problem I'm facing. Not sure how can I include motivation more explicitly, since it's obvious that the motivation is to maximize profit. What edits should I make to make my question on-topic?

Comment: You can reference the source of the problem and include strategies that you think can be used to solve it. Also include relevant attempts in solving the problem. At the very least, you can see what trial and error suggests.

Comment: @BeKind I added a paragraph containing my attempt.

Comment: Try to show, not tell. Show us all the progress you have made with the compound interest formula and point out exactly where you are stuck.

Comment: @BeKind I included a Python script that I've tried.

Comment: What was the output of the Python script? Does it give you any hints to solve the problem? Also, include the math - what logical deductions did you make from the compound interest formula? What is the furthest you could come to in solving the problem?

Comment: @BeKind I included the output and how far I've gone solving the issue.

Comment: Looks good to me. We'll see what the more experienced users on this site have to say. As a side note, it's recommended to use [Mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/1072645) wherever necessary for questions on this site.

Comment: It is not quite clear if this is a math problem, or is it just a problem of writing Python script.

Comment: And I guess you reused some of your previous code for another problem? I don't really see why there is a "gas_fee_in_usd" in your script.

Comment: @ArcticChar It's a math problem, I was just asked to show what I've tried and it happened to be in Pyhton

Comment: @ArcticChar `gas_fee_in_usd` represents the fee of one transaction.

Comment: I suggest you made some edit so that it is a clear math probem that one can answer. Right now it looks like a python script that does not work and you do not know how to modify it.

Comment: @ArcticChar I described the clear math problem in the first half of the question, the Python code is just there to show my progress.

Comment: @ArcticChar I added what I'm looking for (a formula that I can find the maximum of), hopefully, that makes it clearer

Comment: The problem is as a non-Python user, I have absolutely no idea what that script does, and thus no idea where you are stuck.

Comment: @ArcticChar I added some MathJax to show where I'm at

Answer (score -1, accepted):

1. Formatting, see how to write headers, bold text etc in the MSE text editor
2. MSE has a general code-o-phobia in my opinion. There is a reluctance to embrace any type of code beyond math jax, so that maybe a reason for negative perception.
3. One has to read your calculation and reverse engineer what idea you had. If your idea was non sense, reverse engineering is doubly hard.

   3.1. Hence, you should give an outline of the idea before showing the calculation

Comment: Thank you! I edited my question and addressed all three points.

Comment: The math jax is a bit clunky still, but it's way better. Have my upvote. @TamásSengel

Comment: I appreciate your feedback! Please let me know how can I improve the MathJax in the question. Thanks!

Comment: @TamásSengel To write text in math mode, use `$\text{blah blah}$` to produce $\text{blah blah}$. For brackets with large expressions inside, use `$\left(...\right)$` to produce $\left(...\right)$. Another useful feature for aligning equations is `\begin{align}\end{align}`. For more details, see [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/1072645).

Comment: I adjusted the MathJax using your suggestions. @BeKind

Comment: @TamásSengel For the multiplication symbol, I recommend using `$\times$` (produces $\times$) or `$\cdot$` (produces $\cdot$).